# Mapping GSuite custom attribute value via Groups

Tags: g-suite, single-sign-on

So, I have followed instruction here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-single-sign-on-to-aws-using-google-apps/

On how to set up AWS SSO via GSuite.

My issue is, I need to map the a few different value to a large number of users. I'd prefer if I could do it via some kind of groups / org unit where I only have to do it once and have it applied to everyone in the group.

As well as for users to merge / inherit values when they are in multiple groups?

(And not sure if server fault is the correct place to ask .... )